# UNNotificationServiceExtension Notifications filtering doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have a problems with remote notifications filtering .
I have such notification model

```
{
  "headers": {
     "apns-push-type": "alert"
  },

  "aps": {
    "alert": {
            "title": "Test title",
            "body": "You have received a new message."
    },
    "mutable-content": 1
  }
}
```

I can catch it in `UNNotificationServiceExtension` with method

```
func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)
```

But i can't filter notification with `contentHandler(UNNotificationContent())` because it anyway displays new item in notification center.

It seems that according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_usernotifications_filtering) i did everything correct...

> To silence a remote notification, you must set the apns-push-type header field to alert when you send the notification to the APNS server. Otherwise, the system always displays the notification banner to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied that quote from the entitlements section of the Apple documentation.

Do you have the entitlement com.apple.developer.usernotifications.filtering?

If not then you have to apply to Apple for them to grant it to you as it says in the documentation. (The administrator of the Apple account has to apply for it I think, if you're registered as a developer, you won't be able to)

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I think it’s not done yet.